# Run a for loop and if statement over a vector, but doent not work, why?

Tags: r

I want to run this function for this vector. But it doesnt work, does anyone have a suggestion to solve it? Thanks!

```
  pvalue <- c(0.01, 0.9,0.00001,0.50)

  pvalue <- for(i in 1:length(pvalue)) {
    if(pvalue < 0.0001){
      print("<0.0001")
    }  else {
      pvalue <- pvalue
    }
```

Comment: Use `i` to index `pvalue` in loop but why are you doing this? What is your expected output?

Comment: `pvalue2 <- ifelse(pvalue < 0.0001, "<0.0001", pvalue)`

Comment: @Ronak Shah the expected outcome is 0.01,0.9, <0.0001,0.5. How do you mean I can change the function? This is just an example and part of a bigger function, so happy to know whats wrong! :)

Comment: You can use Edward's solution to get your expected output but the wrong part is "<0.0001" is a of class character and when you combine character with other numbers they all are going to be characters.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to run this in a for loop. Simply running this would suffice:

```
pvalue[pvalue < 0.0001] <- "<0.0001"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
value <- c(0.01, 0.9,0.00001,0.50)
options(scipen = 999)
pvalue <- ifelse(value < 0.0001, "<0.0001", value)
pvalue

#[1] "0.01" "0.9"  "<0.0001" "0.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that withou a loop as R simply works with vectors. But be very careful about converting `numeric` vectors to `character`. All the items of vector  need to be of the same class, so in fact you are converting the vector to character class. It's generaly better to keep your numeric data and if you need some kind of adjustment for output (print, plot etc.), adjust that directly there.

```r
pvalue <- c(0.01, 0.9, 0.00001, 0.50)
pvalue
#> [1] 1e-02 9e-01 1e-05 5e-01
class(pvalue)
#> [1] "numeric"

pvalue_char <- ifelse(pvalue < 0.0001, "<0.0001", pvalue)
pvalue_char
#> [1] "0.01"    "0.9"     "<0.0001" "0.5"
class(pvalue_char)
#> [1] "character"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>